# No output from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have this sql query which runs fine when I execute it in MSSQL Management Studio, but when I try to execute it in PHP it gives me no output.

Any suggestions?

//gets ID

```
 $atz_id = $_GET['atz_id'];
```

//SQL query

```
 $q2 = "
 declare @atzID int             set @atzID=$atz_id; 


 if object_id('tempdb..#vesture1') is not null drop table #vesture1
 select distinct
 atz_id,
 datums s_dat,
 cast(NULL as datetime) b_dat,
 tips
 into #vesture1
 from guna..erg2_atzistas_o o
 where
 darbiba=1
 and atz_id=@atzID


  update #vesture1 set b_dat=(select top 1 datums from guna..erg2_atzistas_o where atz_id=#vesture1.atz_id and darbiba=0 and tips=#vesture1.tips and datums > #vesture1.s_dat order by datums asc)


 if object_id('tempdb..#vesture2') is not null drop table #vesture2
 select distinct
 atz_id,
 convert(varchar, s_dat, 104) s_dat,
 convert(varchar, b_dat, 104) b_dat,
 substring((select ', '+tips from #vesture1 where atz_id=v.atz_id and s_dat=v.s_dat and isnull(b_dat,0)=isnull(v.b_dat,0) order by tips for xml path('')), 3, 3000) 'sugas'
into #vesture2
from #vesture1 v

select * from #vesture2 order by s_dat, b_dat
";
```

//runs query

```
$res2=mssql_query($q2);
```

//checks if there is some output (there is not - other queries outputs 0 or number of rows, this one dont)

```
$num_rows2 = mssql_num_rows($res2);


 echo $num_rows2;
```

//outputs data

```
echo "<table border='1' class='saraksts_table' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
<tr class='saraksts_header'>
<th><center><font size='1.2px'>info</font></center></th>
<th><center><font size='1.2px'>xxxx</font></center></th>
<th><center><font size='1.2px'>axxa</font></center></th>
<th><center><font size='1.2px'>SAAAa</font></center></th>
</tr>";

while($row2 = mssql_fetch_array($res2))
{
echo "<tr style=background-color:white;>";
echo "<td>" . $row2['atz_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row2['s_dat'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row2['b_dat'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row2['sugas'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Updated
Error messages :

```
   PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): message: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. (severity 16) in /home/info/info_pub/sql_vesture.php on line 108
   PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 16) in /home/info/info_pub/sql_vesture.php on line 108
   PHP Warning:  mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/info/info_pub/sql_vesture.php on line 112
   PHP Warning:  mssql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/info/info_pub/sql_vesture.php on line 167
```

Comment: When you say no output, do you mean no output whatsoever, or just no rows?

Comment: no output. There must be output, but there isn't.
query works fine in MSSQL management Studio, but when i try to execute in PHP it gives me back nothing. Maybe there is some mistakes in PHP code but i can't find anyone

Comment: Have you tried outputting the count for rows inserted, respectively updated in #vesture1? And have you checked your connection string - that you are on the right server, with a user with the correct rights?

Comment: I'm checking count of rows here - $num_rows2 = mssql_num_rows($res2); echo $num_rows2; - it gives me no output at all. I got second query in same page, it outputs required data and count of rows too (0-if no rows ..) connection to DB is in include file and other queries works fine, so it shouldn't be the problem

Comment: Couldn't you have a fatal php error behind ?

Comment: have you tried to put ";" after your querys?

Comment: I updated question - added error messages, and adding ';' didn't help

Comment: doesn't the first PHP warning say, what the problem is?

Comment: ok - could someone Please explain me what does this warning means and how can i fix it?

Comment: ahah, I have a feeling that mssql_connect failed, which means that `$res2` is false (a boolean). because of that the `num_rows` and `fetch_array` calls aren't working, so check your connection string

Comment: there is two queries, both using the same connection - one works fine, but this-one not, so i assume that connection to db works fine.
- I couldn't find any helpful info about that warning too

Comment: it was worth a try :) i'm sorry I can't help any more, good luck!

Comment: When you have sql errors just keep narrowing the sql down to you find what's causing the issue. I'm sure your aware btw but that code is not security wise safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to convert data type - > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

updated select - took a while to figure it out

```
           select atz_id, s_dat, b_dat, **cast(sugas as varchar)as sugas** from #vesture2 order by s_dat, b_dat;
```

thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

often I will write PHP MySQL queries as 3 steps.

1. define query

   $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value=''";
2. execute query:

   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
3. validate query results:

   if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { }

OR you could combine step 2 and 3 as follows:

```
if (!result = mysql_query($query)) {
    // looks like this didnt return any data
} else {
    // woot, we have something to work with     
}
```

Most often the errors you are seeing means that your query was invalid resulting in a bogus data set to work with, as opposed to returning no rows.

I use the 3 steps as with error reporting on in PHP step 2 will provide you the MySQL feedback error code along with the line in PHP which usually helps you isolate where in the query it went awry.

Comment: +1 for 3 steps! It helps to be able to echo and var_dump() mid-way through to debug. I've never tried the "if (!result = mysql_query($query))" method, but it looks useful.

Comment: basically if the query fails you can do something :) ... it's the same as step 3. Basically Step 2 will tell you if your QUERY is messed up, step 3 will tell you if the results were EMPTY. that should cover most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[global]
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```